# Numbering Matrix Elements

Tags: lua

I am currently using Lua (even though this question is more a question of logic than the language itself) and I'm trying to make a noughts and crosses game. I have a board table that is structured in 3 rows and 3 columns. I want to be able to number each square 1 through 9 as follows:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
and I want to convert these numbers into the coordinates in the table. So 1 = [1, 1], 2 = [2, 1] and 4 = [1, 2] and so on. I've tried a few approaches, but I can't work this out properly. And I don't want to use a switch statement, because I may want to expand the board to 4x4 or 5x5.

Answer (score 2):

To get the row `i`, and the column `j` from the value `aij` you can use:

```
 i = math.floor((aij - 1) / ncols) + 1
 j = (aij - 1) % ncols + 1
 -- alternatively, use i to help compute j
 j = aij - (i - 1) * ncols
```

where `ncols` is the number of columns. And to go back:

```
 aij = (i - 1) * ncols + j
```

For the 3x3 case:

```
local n = 3
for aij=1,n*n do
   local i = math.floor((aij - 1) / n) + 1
   local j = (aij - 1) % n + 1
   print(aij, "["..j..", "..i.."]")
end
```

the output is:

```
1   [1, 1]
2   [2, 1]
3   [3, 1]
4   [1, 2]
5   [2, 2]
6   [3, 2]
7   [1, 3]
8   [2, 3]
9   [3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a matrix with `n` rows.. The coordinates of number `x` is:

- Row `math.floor((x - 1) / n) + 1`.
- Column `x % n == 0 and n or x % n`.